# How can we assign local variable in sub query SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I tried to set a value to variable in sub query but it doesn't work.

Here is my query:

```
declare @val1 int
declare @val2 int

select @val1 = sum(column1) 
,(select @val2 = (select sum(column2) from table2))
,(@val1+@val2)Result
from table 1
```

What I want to do is setting `@val2` for sub query help me please
I meant set in Sub query  not separate select statement

Comment: You need to **show us some code** and you need to **read** and learn from [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why not 3 separate `select` statements?

Comment: i need to use @val2   for many time so my query maybe too long

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use 3 separate selects:

```
select @val1 = sum(column1) from table1 
select @val2 = sum(column2) from table2
select (@val1+@val2) as Result
```

Or you can also write 2 selects:

```
 select @val1 = sum(column1), 
        @val2 = (select SUM(column2) from table2)
 from table1
 select (@val1 + @val2) Result
```

But not just 1 select:

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations

If you need to accomplish all in one select and return a recordset, do not use variables, do it like this:

```
SELECT sum1 + sum2 FROM (
    select sum(column1) as sum1, 
           (select SUM(column2) from table2) as sum2
    from table1
) subquery
```

Comment: my code above is just for example for easy to understand my problem but accually my query for assign to val2 is very long so i have to use it for many time

Comment: I got this error when trying to use your 2nd method   I got this erer : Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Comment: The second method works well, you try to combine the 2 selects into one and that is the problem. If you want to process all in one select and return a recordset,  do not use variables.